# Why does key equivalent work with escape but not with return?

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I have a button on my window that is set in interface builder to have the key equivalent of enter, but after switching a content view from using IKImageBrowserView to NSCollectionView, the keyEquivalent is being ignored.

From what it says in the docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW10

The keyEquivalent events are handled "special" and should be pretty straight forward.

I am subclassing the NSCollectionViewItem and the view of the item but neither of these subclasses are getting the performKeyEquivalent:theEvent when I override that method.

There is a cancel button right next to the default button and is mapped to the esacpe key. Cancel continues to work, but the default button does not.

How can I tell where the enter key event is getting handled?

Edit:

I actually found the same issue in the sample app that I used to learn about NSCollectionView. I added a default button to the bottom of the window and found that return did not trigger the button but enter (fn + return) did trigger the button.

[IconCollection sample app from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IconCollection/Introduction/Intro.html)

Any ideas on what is stealing the return key event in this example?

Edit:

I posted a sample project here: https://github.com/watkyn/NSCollectionViewIssue. Why doesn't the default button work?

Comment: I'm running IconCollection. I'm not seeing a default button anywhere. Is there a window I'm missing?

Comment: I had to add the default button myself. Just made room for it right underneath the collection view. I actually duplicated this issue with a new project with an empty collection view (has to be selectable) and a default button. Not looking good.

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to get return/enter to work with your sample program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Return` and `Enter` are two different keys. `Return` (on a US keyboard) is to the right of the apostrophe key. `Enter` is the lower-right key on the keypad. If you are using a laptop without a numeric keypad, you get `Enter` by pressing `fn`+`Return`.

---

**Edit after sample code was posted**

`MyCollectionView` is absorbing the return/enter keystroke and not passing it up the responder chain. Add this to the implementation of `MyCollectionView` and return and enter will press the button:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
//  NSLog(@"event: %@", theEvent);
    if (36 == theEvent.keyCode || 76 == theEvent.keyCode) {
        //pass return and enter up the responder chain
        [[self window] keyDown:theEvent];
    }
    else {
        //process all other keys in the default manner
        [super keyDown:theEvent];
    }
}
```

This may cause problems if you need MyControllerView to actually do something itself with return/enter. In that case, you can add `[super keyDown:theEvent]` before `[[self window] keyDown:theEvent]`.

Comment: Thanks, I am using IB to set the key equivalent, so I don't think this is the issue. But good to know.

Comment: If the button turns blue, doesn't that mean it is expecting a return key equivalent? The button is blue, but you are right, enter is what triggers it. I must be missing something because it doesn't make sense to me.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I also tried handling this in code with setKeyEquivalent:@"\r" which had the same results. Enter responds, but return does not.

Comment: There may be some cases where Return works, but generally Enter is the key that presses the default button. (Of course I just tested that on Safari's "Save As…" dialog and Return worked.)

Comment: You're right. [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Articles/MakingaButtontheDefaultButton.html) say `setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"` should work. Do you have any text fields in the window? I think they can intercept Return before it gets to the button.

Comment: I posted an update with a sample app from Apple that has the same issue. Very strange.

Comment: It seems to be a bit inconsistent with other types of views, like NSTableView, etc. But, hey, this does work, thanks a lot.

Comment: In general, you have to be really mindful when you change the way default keystrokes behave. If they're not doing what you expect, you should carefully examine your expectations and your design. For example in this case, you may want to use a panel instead of a window. What you really want to avoid is having your program act non-Mac-like. If you find yourself second-guessing system behavior that should always be a red flag. Good luck!